# Finding the projective transformation.

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, cubics

Given a cubic $F(x,y,z)=x^3 + y^2 z + y z^2 = 0$ I have to find projective transformation $\phi : \mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$, such that, $\phi(F) = x^3 + axz^2 + bz^3 - y^2 z = 0$ (Weierstrass normal form).

There is an answer that touches on this subject pretty well:
[Irreducible cubic curve in normal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504361/irreducible-cubic-curve-in-normal-form).

However doing it by the link https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/Matsuura-projective_transformation.pdf given in the answer is very tedious with some cumbersome calculations, on the other hand, ‘guessing’ the transformation seems the way to go. Now in my example, $F$ already appears to be close to normal form(by mapping $z \rightarrow -z$ I get $y^2z = x^3 + yz^2)$ so idealy would be  to transform $yz^2 \rightarrow axz^2 +bz^3$ but I do not think this is possible without altering other part off the cubic.I tried something like $x \rightarrow x+z$ and $z \rightarrow x+z$ and nothing nice came out. Any ideas how to it without too much computation?

Comment: A generic cubic is of the form $$cx^3 + ex^2y + fx^2z + gxy^2 + hxyz + axz^2 + my^3 + dy^2z + nyz^2 + bz^3 = 0$$ i.e. you have $\binom52=10$ coefficients. A generic projective transformation is a $3\times3$ matrix so it has 9 entries. In the normal form you cite, you fix $e=f=g=h=m=n=0$, $c=1$ and $d=-1$. So plugging the transformed point into your original equation and then doing this coefficient comparison, you would end up with 8 equations that are cubic in the 9 entries of the matrix. I would expect one or more one-parameter families of such transformations. No fun approach.